# Passando um array via Ajax para view Django

Tags: ajax, django, view

Pretendo passar um array via Ajax para a minha view do Django,mas sempre ocorre um erro

> stream_or_string = stream_or_string.read()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'ajax/',
         type: 'POST', 
         dataType: "json",
         data: {disciplina: array_list}, 
         success: function(data) {
              //alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
         },
         failure: function(data) { 
              //alert("Ocorreu um erro, realize a operação novamente");
         }
    }).done(function(data){
        //alert(data);
    });
```

**view.py**

```
for lista in serializers.deserialize("json", request.POST.get('disciplina')):
    idDisciplina = [lista]
```

Caso eu faço algo desse tipo

```
num=request.POST.get('disciplina')
```

Ele ainda recebe caso eu passe apenas um único valor e não um array

Deserialize usei baseado no que achei, mais não entendi bem ainda a sua funcionalidade, alguém pode ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você deve informar o **csrf token** para poder submeter via metódo `'POST'` de forma segura. Segundo, quando você envia um array, django recebe a variável com colchetes no final dela, no caso seria: `request.POST.get('disciplina[]')`.

Veja como é recebido (neste exemplo fiz um array `['a', 'b']` como exemplo:

```
>>> print(request.POST)
<QueryDict: {'disciplina[]': ['a', 'b'], ...>
```

Veja que sem colchetes a variável não existe:

```
>>> print(request.POST.get('disciplina'))
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'disciplina'"
```

Com colchetes:

```
>>> print(request.POST.get('disciplina[]'))
b
```

Como você pode notar, dessa forma é capturado apenas o último item do array. Para pegar todos os itens você deve usar `getlist`:

```
>>> meu_array = request.POST.getlist('disciplina[]')
>>> print(meu_array)
['a', 'b']
```

Para enviar com csrf, você pode adicionar o `csrfmiddlewaretoken` ao dicionário:

```
<script>

    var array_list = ['a', 'b'];

    $.ajax({
         url: '{% url "core:teste" %}',
         method: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {disciplina: array_list, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
         success: function(data) {
              alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
         },
         failure: function(data) {
              alert("Ocorreu um erro, realize a operação novamente");
         }
    }).done(function(data){
        //alert(data);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Vou estar testando e falo se funcionou, mas ainda estou com uma duvida pra q a utilização do serializers? Se pode-se usar um ex básico ajudaria mut